# Double colon in docker-compose volumes?

Tags: docker-compose, keycloak

I was looking over [this Keycloak issue on Github](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/10216) and noticed that in the example this person gives of a `docker-compose` configuration for Keycloak, the volume has two colons:

```
keycloak:
  image: "quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:16.1.1"
  environment:
    - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/tmp/realm.json
  volumes:
    - ./realm.json:/tmp/realm.json:ro
```

Now I know what one colon does but I was looking on the docker compose documentation but I can't find an explanation for what two colons is supposed to do. So what does having two colons do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second colon allows you set certain options for the mount; this is documented in [`docker run` manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/#volumes-from). Your options are:

- `ro` -- make the mount read-only
- `rw` -- make the mount read-write (the default)
- `z`, `Z` -- control selinux labels on the volume (see the docs for more info)